# Capturing still images using AVFoundation's AVCaptureSession is slow (iPhone 4S camera)

Tags: ios, performance, image, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm experiencing performance issues when taking still images with `AVCaptureSession`. The `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` method of `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` seems to be quite slow with larger images (`AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` on iPhone 4S). It works perfect though for the lower presets/resolutions (including iPod touch's camera). I also tried the WWDC sample code AVCam and also got a delay from when the picture was taken to the point when I could actually display it in an `UIImageView`.
Is there a faster, more efficient way than making a `UIImage` from `NSData` (got from `[AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer]`)?

I could alternatively display a HUD message that the image is being processed or set a lower quality preset, but the fact that I'm actually even experiencing a delay is annoying me.

Just to mention - I'm also cropping/resizing the image after the user snaps it and that adds a bit more to the delay, but not much.

Thanks for all the suggestions/anwsers!

Comment: ~2 seconds. I'm considering another solution - capturing the preview layer as an `UIImage` and then temporarily displaying it until the `UIImage` processing is done.

Comment: turns out you can't "capture" the preview layer ...

Comment: Hi Jure, have you managed to solve that problem? I'm working on an application where I need to show the camera feed to the user while without the user's knowledge keep capturing frames for processing. These processed frames do not have visual output, so only capturing as UIImage will suffice. Do you have any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can try something with AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and use that to generate images. Follow the [link to apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer)